# Is it possible to gain computer access via Apache2 server?

Tags: networking, apache2, firewall

Im runnning Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and apparently firewall is not enabled by default.
I cant recall installing apache2 webserver but I found out it was hosting the welcome page on port 80.

I dont know very much about networking but somehow this page was publicly exposed.
I disabled it now  but there is an extensive list of connections in `/var/log/apache2/acces.log`.

Some of the connections:

```
8.25 Safari/537.36"
157.33.87.249 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:25:08 +0100] "GET http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.9.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
123.240.216.151 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:25:10 +0100] "CONNECT cn.aol.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 405 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
51.210.41.62 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:25:31 +0100] "GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
51.210.41.62 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:25:31 +0100] "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 405 505 "-" "-"
20.188.62.120 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:25:33 +0100] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
5.188.211.15 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:26:20 +0100] "POST http://5.188.211.72/check.php HTTP/1.1" 404 454 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
142.54.173.35 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:26:59 +0100] "GET http://gamenewss.com/steyt1.php HTTP/1.1" 404 436 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.734 Safari/537.36"
142.54.173.35 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:00 +0100] "GET http://gamenewss.com/steyt1.php HTTP/1.1" 404 455 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36/M8ZW4tNE-18"
188.134.5.43 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:12 +0100] "GET /proxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 444 "RefererString" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
142.54.173.35 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:19 +0100] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
98.148.170.224 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:28 +0100] "CONNECT 142.250.72.228:443 HTTP/1.0" 405 524 "-" "-"
188.134.5.43 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:30 +0100] "CONNECT chekfast.zennolab.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
98.148.170.224 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:33 +0100] "\x04\x01\x01\xbb\x8e\xfaH\xe4" 400 0 "-" "-"
98.148.170.224 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:39 +0100] "\x05\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
98.148.170.224 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:39 +0100] "GET https://www.google.com/search?q=%search% HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20060127 Netscape/8.1"
101.206.1.250 - - [08/Jan/2021:12:27:40 +0100] "CONNECT tz.gxout.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 405 503 "-"
```

What are these connections and how bad is this? Have these connections tried to make my computer execute these requests? To what extend could my files have been accessed?

Answer (score 3):

They're scripts and bots running on remote computers trying to probe your server, looking for vulnerabilities. If your system is outdated, and they happen to poke the right hole, yes, they could get in. They could then use your computer for nefarious purposes. If your system was up to date, and you didn't make silly changes to permissions of files, and didn't install old/unsafe copies of web applications (like php based things) chances are you're safe.